# How to get records by using 3 tables or work with 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been asked this question in an interview. I have tried so hard, but unfortunately was not able to get it right.can anybody help me with this?

**Retrieve the last name, first name, dept name of that employee using these tables.I am writing down the tables and columns.however, i am not writing that dummy data.**

Employee- (id, last name, first name, DOB, SSN) and some other columns(not useful).
Dept - (D_id, dept name)
Emp_Dept - (id, D_id)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: This is a pretty simple `JOIN` query.  You should study some SQL or remove SQL from your resume.

Comment: ok @GordonLinoff  i will keep this in mind. Anyways, i know SQL Basics and i will learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution for your problem :

`Query :`

```
SELECT E.last_name, E.first_name, D.dept_name
FROM Employee AS E
-- Get employee dept
INNER JOIN Emp_Dept AS ED
ON ED.id = E.id
-- get dept data
INNER JOIN Dept AS D
ON D.id = ED.D_id
```

I hope it will help you.

But this query doesn't return value of employee without dept. If this is necessary you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`